# Android studio 2.3.1 32bit "Please provide path to android studio"

Tags: android-studio, path, sdk, windows-7, 32-bit

I have installed a 32-bit version of Android studio 2.3.1 on my windows 7 32-bit machine which is **"No Android SDK, no installer**". I have tried the 1.8 GB version of Android stdio but it is not compatible with my system. After running it gives an error which is in 2nd snap shot.

Can anyone help me in resolving the issue of Android studio 2.3.1 32-bit:

> "Please provide path to android studio".

I have tried the 64-bit version on 64-bit machine - it is working fine, but the problem is with 32-bit version.

Comment: hi @ashin-ashin, please provide some screen capture. Your question is difficult to read, this os the least to say

Answer (score 0):

There is no installer available or SDK along with android studio in 32bit version. 
Extract the zip file downloaded, go to the "bin" directory and run the studio.exe file, it will start installing the android studio on your PC.

here's a link to download the 32bit version. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

When it asks for SDK path,
Try this - C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Replace your name with the name of your PC.

You might consider this link as useful.

https://techglimpse.com/solution-fix-android-sdk-studio-error/